# DepDrop Widget Kartik Yii2

Tags: yii2

Primera consulta que hago después de sacarme las castañas mil veces en esta página, pero ya ando algo desesperado con un tema que debe ser o debería ser sencillo.

Usar `DepDrop` de las librerías de Kartik para Yii2, un trabajo excelente. Necesito usar el plugin dependent drep drop, me parecía fácil, pero me ha sido imposible.

Tengo las tablas y modelos `provincia` y `localidad`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la vista tengo:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?php  $provinciaList = ArrayHelper::map(Provincia::find()->orderBy('provincia')->all(), 'idprovincia', 'provincia'); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'provincia_idprovincia')->dropDownList
        ($provinciaList, ['id'=>'proveedor-provincia_idprovincia']);?>

<?=
$form->field($model, 'localidad_idlocalidad')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
'options'=>['id'=>'proveedor-localidad_idlocalidad'],
'pluginOptions'=>[
    'depends'=>['proveedor-provincia_idprovincia'],
    'placeholder'=>'Selecciona una localidad...',
    'url'=>Url::to(['/localidad/localidades'])
]
]); ?> 
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

En el controlador de la localidad llamado por `'url'=>Url::to(['/localidad/localidades'])`:

```
public function actionLocalidades() {
    $out = [];


    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
    $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];

    if ($parents != null) {

    $provid = $parents[0];

    $out = Localidad::Localidades($provid);

    print_r($out);

    echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
    return;
    }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
    }
```

En el modelo localidad:

```
public static function getLocalidades($provid) 
{

    $data=  \app\models\Localidad::find()
   ->where(['provincia_idprovincia'=>$provid])
   ->select(['idlocalidad as id','localidad as name'])->asArray()->all();

   return $data;
}
```

En el primer dropbox aparecen todas las provincias, al seleccionar una sale en el campo dependiente un Loading, pero no se carga la lista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias si alguien puede echarme una mano.

Comment: En el controlador reemplazar return; por exit;

Answer (score 2):

Asegúrate de eliminar la línea que dice:

```
print_r($out);
```

Esta genera una salida que no está en el formato esperado por el plugin.

Si el problema persiste a pesar de esto remplaza las líneas:

```
 if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
    $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
```

Por

```
 $parents = "algun idprovincia valido"
```

Y ajusta las } correspondientes.

Luego entra a tupagina/localidad/localidades para verificar que la salida es en un formato similar a lo siguiente:

```
{
    "output":[
        {"id":"1","name":"Mobile Phones"},
        {"id":"2","name":"Tablets"},
        {"id":"3","name":"Computers & Accessories"},
        {"id":"4","name":"Cameras"},
        {"id":"5","name":"Televisons"}
    ],
    "selected":"3"
}
```

Cuando consigas la salida adecuada remplaza nuevamente las líneas y } a su estado original.

```
 if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
    $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
```